# T-SQL select row if one specific column's decimal part is not 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with one of the columns : `cost`, it is of decimal type with 2 d.p.

Now I would like to select all rows from this table  where `cost`'s decimal part is not 0

For example,  I do not select the row if `cost` is 150.00 or 222.00,  but would like to select if `cost` is 0.20 or 123.12, etc.

How can this be done in a single select query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For rows where there is a zero decimal part [`Floor(cost)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx) will equal `cost` and it won't where there is a non zero decimal part.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE Floor(cost) <> cost;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from table1
WHERE
convert(decimal(10,0), cost) <> cost
```